# Java calling method and trapping return

Tags: java, methods, return-value

I'm having a problem calling a method and then trapping its return.

I need it to update the result so the next time round the loop it will see it and return a different message.

```
public class Patient {

private char patientStatus;

public boolean admit() {

    if (patientStatus != 'S')
        return false;

    else
        patientStatus = 'A';
    return true;
}
```

This section is in the main() method

```
do {
        Patient temp = null;
        System.out.print("Enter selection: ");
        menuSelect = sc.nextLine();

        // validation

        if (menuSelect.length() != 1) {
            System.out.println("You must enter a single character");
        } else {
            menuAnswer = menuSelect.charAt(0);
            switch (menuAnswer) {
            case 'A':
            case 'a':

                // patient number

                System.out.print("Enter patient number: ");
                patNumber = sc.nextLine();

                // search for patient number

                for (int i = 0; i < pat.length && temp == null; i++) {
                    if (pat[i].getPatientNo().equals(patNumber)) {
                        temp = pat[i];
                    }
                }

                if (temp == null) {
                    System.out.println("Patient not found");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Patient " + patNumber + " Found");

                    boolean patStatus = temp.admit();

                    if (patStatus == false) {
                        System.out.println("Admitted");

                    } else if (patStatus == true) {
                        System.out.println("Already admitted");
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    } while (menuAnswer != 'x' && menuAnswer != 'X');
    System.out.println("Exiting menu");
```

I don't know how to update the patStatus so the next time in the menu if you select 'A' and the same patient number it returns "Already admitted".

Let me know if there's enough code to understand what's happening.

Comment: You are not storing the object

Comment: // You have to re-factor the code on these lines. Maintain Patients class which holds admitted patients.

public class Patients{

 private ConcurrentMap<Integer, Patient> admittedPatients = new ConcurrentHashMap();

 public Patients(){

 }
 public void adminPatient(Patient p){
  admittedPatients.put(p.getPatientId(),p);
 }
 public Patient dischargePatient(int patientId){
  return admittedPatients.remove(patientId);
 }
}

Answer (score 1):

Your `Patient` has the atribute for `patientStatus` but its value is never saved. Your `admit()` method needs to set the value for it.

Currently, your code only returns the value but does not save it.
Try this:

```
public class Patient {

private char patientStatus;

/** "Getter" method for patientStatus
*/
public char getPatientStatus(){
    return patientStatus;
}

/** "Admits" the new patient, changing its patientStatus
* @return "true" if patient is admitted; "false" if patient was already admitted.
*/
public boolean admit() {

    if (patientStatus != 'A')
        patientStatus = 'A'; //set the value to Admitted
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

}
```

Then, in your loop, test the value for the `admit()` call:

```
if (temp == null) {
    System.out.println("Patient not found");
} else {
    System.out.println("Patient " + patNumber + " Found");

    boolean admitted = temp.admit(); // try to admit the patient

    if (admitted) {
        System.out.println("Admitted");
    } else { //You don't need another if here
        System.out.println("Already admitted");
    }
}
```

Since `admitted` is of type `boolean`, you don't need to use the `==` operator, as the `if` statement uses a `boolean` value as argument.

You don't need a second `if` statement after the `else` either, since `boolean` can only have two values, if it is not `true`, then it can only be `false`

Comment: This has the same issue as his code. You're not saving the value of `temp`, so it's as if nothing has happened the next time the `do-while` runs.

Comment: No. The _Object_ for the Patient is saved inside his `pat` array. You don't need to keep another reference to it, since on the next time it will be searched again on his `for` loop

Comment: I'm aware. But you're not changing the value of said object in his `pat` array.

Comment: Yes, I am. `pat` is an array of an `Object` type. it does not holds the objects themselves, instead, it only holds references to said objects in the memory. You you return `pat[i]`, you are returning a reference to an object, and any changes made in the variable `temp` are performed in the same object inside `pat`.

Answer (score 0):

```
   /* You have to re-factor the code on these lines. 
   Maintain Patients class which holds admitted patients.*/

public class Patients{

    private ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Patient> allPatients = new ConcurrentHashMap();
    private HashSet<Integer) admittedPatients = new HashSet();

    public Patients(){

    }
    public void add(Patient p){
        allPatients.put(p.getPatientId(),p);
    }
    public Patient removePatient(int patientId){
        dischargePatients.remove(patientId);
        return allPatients.remove(patientId);
    }
    public Patient getPatient(int patientId){
        return allPatients.get(patientId);
    }
    public void admitPatient(int patientId){
        admittedPatients.add(patientId);
    }
    public boolean dischargePatient(int patientId){
        return admittedPatients.remove(patientId);
    }
    public boolean isAdmittedPatient(int patientId){
         return admittedPatients.contains(patentId);
    }
}

From `Patient.java` class, you can admit & discharge patient.
```

If `getPatient()` is `null` implies patient is not present in list. 
Once he is present, isAdmittedPatient returns whether 
he is admitted or not.

Comment: That seems to be a bit overkill for his problem... it also uses concepts I am not sure he understands, as it seems he is a beginner in java programming.

Comment: Also. You don't need a `Map` to keep the atributes for every patient, the Patient _object_ should be able to keep all its atributes itself.